# Local variable with same name as instance variable = unexpected results

Tags: c#, instance-variables, local-variables

ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms project.  I have the following in my code-behind.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string testVar;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        string testVar = "test";
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var whatsTheValue = testVar;
    }
}
```

I'm setting a break point inside each method.  When the local variable, `testVar`, is set in `OnInit`, if I quick watch the instance variable, it also has the value "test".  When I play through to `Page_Load`, the instance variable's value is `null`.

I ran across this by accident but the behavior is confusing to me.  I'm actually surprised that it compiles.  I would have expected to see some sort of warning about having two variables with the same name.  That being said, it's even more confusing to me that the instance variable picks up the assignment in OnInit, but then immediately loses it when that method is exited.

Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: How are you watching the instance variable? Perhaps you are watching the local variable instead?

Comment: I think it's more likely that you are either looking at the local variable in the debugger and not the instance variable, or else the debugger is bugged and is displaying the value from the local variable as the value of the instance variable.

Comment: ReSharper gives warnings about this sort of thing, as does my common sense. After learning the behaviour, please change the name of one of those :-)

Comment: This is purely a guess, but I guess that what you are seeing is the debugger being confused. Have  you tried to insert f.e.: String testVar2 = this.testVar; in OnInit()? My guess is you'd still see testVar2 being null.
As to why it compiles, it is not illegal to have a local variable with the same name as an instance variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> if I quick watch the instance variable, it also has the value "test".
> When I play through to Page_Load, the instance variable's value is
> null.

You are **not** seeing the instance variable, you see the local variable. The instance variable is never set, because the locally scoped variable is hiding the instance variable during it's scope lifetime.

From the spec:

> **3.7.1 Name hiding**
>
> The scope of an entity typically encompasses more program text than the declaration space of the entity. In particular,
> the scope of an entity may include declarations that introduce new
> declaration spaces containing entities of the same name. **Such
> declarations cause the original entity to become hidden**. Conversely,
> an entity is said to be visible when it is not hidden.
>
> Name hiding
> occurs when scopes overlap through nesting and when scopes overlap
> through inheritance. The characteristics of the two types of hiding
> are described in the following sections.
>
> Name hiding through nesting can occur as a result of nesting
> namespaces or types within namespaces, as a result of nesting types
> within classes or structs, **and as a result of parameter and local
> variable declarations**

Comment: True. If you want to see the member variable, type `this.testVar` into your Watch window.

Comment: Isn't this a debugger bug? If i hover over a variable, shouldn't it show the value of the variable under the mouse instead of showing the value of the local variable? Same behaviour in VS 2015.

Answer (score 16):

BrokenGlass's answer is of course correct; you are not looking at the field in the first place. The local *hides* the field.

However, I note that no one has addressed this portion of your question:

> I'm actually surprised that it compiles. I would have expected to see some sort of warning about having two variables with the same name.

The C# compiler does not issue an error or warning in that case because doing so would create a form of "brittle base class failure". Suppose you have this code:

```
class B { }

class D : B 
{ 
    void M() 
    { 
        int x;
        ...
```

where B is made by one team in your organization, and D is made by an entirely different team. Then one day the maintainers of B decides to add a feature that needs a protected field:

```
class B { protected int x; }
```

**When you recompile D, should it give an error?**  If it does, then someone on a completely different team just broke *your* code!  C# has been carefully designed to minimize (though not eliminate) this kind of breakage.

Note that C# *does* give an error if you re-use x to mean two different things *in the same code block*. For example:

```
class B { protected int x; }
class D : B 
{ 
    void M() 
    { 
        x = 123; // meaning this.x inherited from B
        if (whatever)
        {
            int x = 10;
            ...
```

That's illegal because now in the body of M, the simple name `x` is used to mean both `this.x` *and* local variable `x`. Because this is potentially confusing and a bad programming practice, we make it an error. However, if you really want that then you can eliminate the error by ensuring that the usages are in *entirely separate blocks:

```
class B { protected int x; }
class D : B 
{ 
    void M() 
    { 
        {
            x = 123; // meaning this.x inherited from B
        }
        if (whatever)
        {
            int x = 10;
```

Now the blocks do not overlap and therefore the compiler assumes that you know what you are doing and allows the code to compile.

Answer (score 0):

> 'm setting a break point inside each method. When the local variable,
>   testVar, is set in OnInit, if I quick watch the instance variable, it
>   also has the value "test". When I play through to Page_Load, the
>   instance variable's value is null.

The thing is that the Watch of VisualStudio based on naming of the variable in the moment of breakpoint hint. So when breakpoint is hitted inside `OnInit` method, even if debugger shows you that *instance* variable has value, this is a wrong *visualization* of the data.

So everything is fine, only *visualization* of the data is not correct.